# Mongodb:Failed to connect

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, ubuntu

I am new to MongoDB.I installed mongodb and used with Laravel framework.Its had been worked for a long time without any issues.But currently while i try to acess my website it shows:

```
 Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused
```

when i try to acces mongodb via command line,it shows:

```
 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111    Connection refused
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146 exception: connect failed
```

when i try to access it via rock tool,it shows:

```
Unable to connect MongoDB, please check your configurations. MongoDB said:Failed to connect to: 127.0.0.1:27017: Connection refused.
```

what i will do? I can't figure what's wrong from my part since its working after the past months.I do nothing since the last days.Thanks in advance..

Comment: I guess you've checked that the MongoD process is running?

Comment: i tried.but i get the same error msg:Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short break, I can find out the solution.
The origin of that issue is the unexpected shutdown of the system.So i run the below code in command prompt:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
mongod --repair
sudo service mongodb start
```

then after the above code run, its working fine :)